# Unable to insert different datatype values in Database

Tags: sql, groovy, resultset

I am trying to migrate data from one database to another but unable to do so due to unable to properly handle the datatypes.

**Schema of Target database**

```
CREATE TABLE `Report_aggregation` (

  `Supplier` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Product_code` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Product_Name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Balance_on_Hand` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Pending` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Sale_Yesterday` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Stock_day` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Sale_avg` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Stock_day_avg` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Lead_time` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Frequency_per_week` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Saftey_stock` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Forecast_order_qty` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Here is how I am inserting values.

```
setValues: { ps, i ->
                    ps.setString(1, contracts[i].Supplier.toString())
                    ps.setInt(2, contracts[i].Product_code)
                    ps.setString(3, contracts[i].Product_Name.toString())
                    ps.setInt(4, contracts[i].Balance_on_Hand)
                    ps.setInt(5, contracts[i].Pending)
                    ps.setInt(6, contracts[i].Sale_Yesterday)
                    ps.setDecimal(7, contracts[i].Stock_day)
                    ps.setDecimal(8, contracts[i].Sale_avg)
                    ps.setString(9, contracts[i].Stock_day_avg.toString())
                    ps.setInt(10, contracts[i].Lead_time)
                    ps.setInt(11, contracts[i].Frequency_per_week)
                    ps.setInt(12, contracts[i].Saftey_stock)
                    ps.setInt(13, contracts[i].Forecast_order_qty)
                }
```

where `contracts` is my resultSet from some other database.

I get this exception upon execution.

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.jolbox.bonecp.PreparedStatementHandle.setInt() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer, null) values: [2, null]
```

I am new to groovy and unable to debug properly, may be I am missing something very basic.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The issue was due to Null values in resultSet.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is problem in line
`ps.setInt(2, contracts[i].Product_code)`

You are inserting into preprared statement null and groovy cannot resolve type so it throws exception about MissingMethodException.

Maybye try :

`ps.setInt(2, contracts[i].Product_code as Integer)`

It will tell groovy that value you are passing is type of Integer, even if it's null.

You can also use ResultSet's methods like `getLong`, or `getInt`. It should solve your problem too.

More information about these methods :
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Yes you are right its because of Null, inserting value properly solved this issue.

Comment: But the exception will be thrown if You pass null, for example erasing column value.

Comment: Yeah actually the resultSet was not getting populated and it was trying to resolve Null value to integer.
After making sure that there are no Nulls the problem was solved.